# Remove elements from an array according to empty elements of another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I want to remove elements from an array only if exist empty elements in another array. I have this:

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Naranja", "Manzana", "Mango", "Fresa", "Limón", "Lima", "Sandia"];
var vegetales = ["", "Ajo", "", "Cebolla", "Tomate", "", "", "Zanahoria"];
    
// The output should be this:
// ["Naranja", "Mango", "Fresa", "Sandia"]
function myFunction() {
  for (var i in vegetales) {
    if (vegetales[i] == '') {
      frutaAeliminar = fruits[i];
      indexFruta = fruits.indexOf(frutaAeliminar);
      if (indexFruta != -1) {
        fruits.splice(indexFruta, 1)
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(fruits);
}

myFunction();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're getting mixed up because you're changing the length of the array while looping through it.  This solution uses a third array to push results to w/o changing the original arrays.

Also, a few quick reminders:

1. Use `for...in` only for iterating over object key/value pairs-- otherwise use a standard `for` loop.
2. Don't forget to declare your variables w/ a `var` statement --otherwise you're going to pollute the global namespace.

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Naranja", "Manzana", "Mango", "Fresa", "Limón", "Lima", "Sandia"];
var vegetales = ["", "Ajo", "", "Cebolla", "Tomate", "", "", "Zanahoria"];

var i;

var outputArr = [];

// The output should be this:
// ["Naranja", "Mango", "Fresa", "Sandia"]

function myFunction() {
  for (i=0; i<vegetales.length; i++) {
    if (vegetales[i] !== '') {
      outputArr.push(fruits[i]);
    }
  }
  console.log(outputArr);
}

myFunction();
```

Answer (score 2):

Example using ES6

Use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=control) and using `&&` in a ternary allows us to not bother with `else` if it's not needed

```js
const fruits = ["Banana", "Naranja", "Manzana", "Mango", "Fresa", "Limón", "Lima", "Sandia"];
const vegetales = ["", "Ajo", "", "Cebolla", "Tomate", "", "", "Zanahoria"];

/* only pick if corresponding array item does not equal '' */ 
const newArray = fruits.filter((fruit, idx) => (vegetales[idx] !== '' && fruit))

console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could filter with the truthy value of the corresponding `vegetales` item.

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Naranja", "Manzana", "Mango", "Fresa", "Limón", "Lima", "Sandia"];
    vegetales = ["", "Ajo", "", "Cebolla", "Tomate", "", "", "Zanahoria"],
    newArray = fruits.filter((_, i) => vegetales[i]);

console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: Slick - reduced me even more!

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution:

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Naranja", "Manzana", "Mango", "Fresa", "Limón", "Lima", "Sandia"];
var vegetales = ["", "Ajo", "", "Cebolla", "Tomate", "", "", "Zanahoria"];
var result = [];
for(var i = 0;i<fruits.length;i++){
    if(vegetales[i]!=""){
        result.push(fruits[i]);
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

Output:

```
["Naranja", "Mango", "Fresa", "Sandia"]
```

Run here:

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Naranja", "Manzana", "Mango", "Fresa", "Limón", "Lima", "Sandia"];
var vegetales = ["", "Ajo", "", "Cebolla", "Tomate", "", "", "Zanahoria"];
var result = [];
for(var i = 0;i<fruits.length;i++){
 if(vegetales[i]!=""){
  result.push(fruits[i]);
 }
}
console.log(result);
```

N.B.: Modification can be made.